# Failure of rsync to detect new files and directory

Tags: shell-script, rsync, backup

I have been performing backups to a remote machine via rsync for several years. At least over the past two months, rsync has stopped detecting new files and directories on the machine to be backed up. The output of the script says that files and directories are up to date even if they are new enough not to exist in any version on the remote machine!

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# MAKE SURE HAVE CORRECT REMOTE/AT-HOME LOGIN SETUP AND THAT TARGET IS TOTEMDOC and source is Documents
#
 rsync -azvv -e "ssh -o CheckHostIP=no -i /home/stefan/.ssh/id_rsa" /home/stefan/Documents remoteUser@MouseHouse:/totembackup/totemdoc
```

Output:

```
opening connection using: ssh -o CheckHostIP=no -i /home/stefan/.ssh/id_rsa -l totem MouseHouse rsync --server -vvlogDtprze.iLsfxC . /totembackup/totemdoc  (13 args)
sending incremental file list
delta-transmission enabled
```

Then a list that every file is up to date, then the conclusion:

```
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=0

sent 407,686 bytes  received 794,633 bytes  801,546.00 bytes/sec
```

What is going wrong? Why can't rsync detect changes in files, or even detect newly-created files?

Comment: The affected files are listed?

Comment: Is the clock accurate (or more specifically, the same) on local and remote system?

Comment: The clock time was different, the local machine was between five and seven hours ahead of the remote machine the last two months. However both are now are on the same time and the problem persists.

Comment: 1. On the source, are the files' timestamps in the future (it shouldn't matter, mind)? 2. Do  the files already exist on the destination, or is `rsync` skipping even new files?

Comment: rsync is skipping even new files. It says that they are up to date when they don't even exist on the remote machine. Now the machines are in the same time, but the source machine was ahead. Files that were created weeks ago will of course show up as having been created in the past, no matter the timezone, though.

Comment: Suggest that you add `-i` to the flags for rsync.  It should then spit out a line for every file it finds.  Please put in your question whether the missing files are listed, and if they are listed, what the string beside them is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there was an unrelated stupid mistake in my script. The files were up to date all along, the script just wasn't copying them to where I thought it was.

At some point modifying the script I must have accidentally removed the trailing slash in the source path. This means that the script changed behaviour from copying into `/totembackup/totemdoc`
to copying into `/totembackup/totemdoc/Documents`. I never noticed this new directory`Documents` when browsing `/totembackup/totemdoc` to check if the backups were working.

Restoring the source path to `/home/stefan/Documents/` (note the trailing slash) returned the script's behaviour to what I expected.